# How to specify the color for a partial histogram patch

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

- I would like to produce the following graph

  - Note that one bar is partially blue and partially teal. This is what I'm trying to reproduce

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

# plt parameters
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10.0, 10.0)
plt.style.use('seaborn-dark-palette')
plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True
plt.rcParams["patch.force_edgecolor"] = True

# data
np.random.seed(365)
replicates = np.random.normal(0.0011542834124829882, 1.6243483937004772, 10000)

mean_diff = 1.1582360922659518

# plot replicates
#  p = sns.distplot(replicates, bins=30, )

# distplot is deprecated, so use histplot
p = sns.histplot(replicates, bins=30, stat='density')

# add the vertical line
plt.vlines(mean_diff, 0, 0.25, color='r', label='mean')

# add the annotation
plt.annotate('p-value', xy=(3.5, 0.05), weight='bold', color='teal',
             xytext=(4, 0.15), fontsize=15, arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color='teal'))

# color bars greater than mean_diff except the partial bar
for rectangle in p.patches:
    if rectangle.get_x() >= mean_diff:
        rectangle.set_facecolor('teal')

# I tried adding a Rectangle of the following dimensions, but it didn't color the rectangle 
Rectangle(xy=(mean_diff, 0), width=1.28523-mean_diff, height=0.206371, angle=0).set_facecolor('teal')

# add cosmetics
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('PDF')
plt.xlabel('PA - OH mean percent replicate vote difference')
plt.show()
```

- `Rectangle(xy=(0.876747, 0), width=0.408487, height=0.206371, angle=0)` is the Rectangle that needs to be partially colored.

  - `Rectangle(xy=(1.28523, 0), width=0.408487, height=0.150066, angle=0)` is the patch immediately after, which is colored `Teal`

### Plot generated by my code

- Note the partial bar, beginning at the mean, is not `teal`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

# plt parameters
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10.0, 10.0)
plt.style.use('seaborn-dark-palette')
plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True
plt.rcParams["patch.force_edgecolor"] = True

# data
np.random.seed(365)
replicates = np.random.normal(0.0011542834124829882, 1.6243483937004772, 10000)

mean_diff = 1.1582360922659518

# plot replicates
p = sns.distplot(replicates, bins=30)

# add the vertical line
plt.vlines(mean_diff, 0, 0.25, color='r', label='mean', colors="r")

# add the annotation
plt.annotate('p-value', xy=(3.5, 0.05), weight='bold', color='teal',
             xytext=(4, 0.15), fontsize=15, arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color='teal'))

# color bars greater than mean_diff except the partial bar
for rectangle in p.patches:
    if rectangle.get_x() >= mean_diff:
        rectangle.set_facecolor('teal')

# I tried adding a Rectangle of the following dimensions, but it didn't color the rectangle
width = 1.28523-mean_diff
plt.bar(x=mean_diff+0.5*width,height=0.206371,width=width,color="#99cccc",edgecolor="#7a7d89")
plt.show()
```

This adds the bar in a matching manner. A bit hacky as we said before.
[image]

Comment: Why did you choose `#99cccc`? I see that `teal` shows up darker.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too so I used a color picker to find the hex value of the color that was actually used on the graph. Same for the outline color.

Comment: Glad I could help