# Matplotlib histogram with highlight

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to create a histogram in python's matplotlib with a (colored) highlight bellow certain threshold (that does not necessarily coincide with the edge of a bin). How can I paint the histogram bellow orange line with blue color?

Please see the desired example:

[image: desired example]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I specify the color for a partial histogram patch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62737627/how-can-i-specify-the-color-for-a-partial-histogram-patch)

Answer (score 0):

Let's try plotting the bars again on top of the histograms:

```
samples = np.random.normal(0,100,10000)

hist, bins = np.histogram(samples, bins=20)

thresh = -200

mask = bins < thresh
below_thresh = np.array(bins[mask].tolist() + [thresh])

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

# original histogram
plt.bar(bins[:-1],hist, width=np.diff(bins), color='C0', align='edge');

# below threshold
plt.bar(below_thresh[:-1], hist[mask[:-1]], 
        width=np.diff(below_thresh), color='C1',
        align='edge')
```

Output:

[image]